# multiprocessing, threading gets stuck and printing output gets messed up

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm running multiple threads in python. I've tried using threading module, multiprocessing module. Even though the execution gives the correct result, everytime the terminal gets stuck and printing of the output gets messed up.
Here's a simplified version of the code.

```
import subprocess
import threading
import argparse
import sys

result = []

def check_thread(args,components,id):
    for i in components:
        cmd = <command to be given to terminal>
        output = subprocess.check_output([cmd],shell=True)
        result.append((id,i,output))

def check(args,components):
    # lock = threading.Lock()
    # lock = threading.Semaphore(value=1)
    thread_list = []
    for id in range(3):
        t=threading.Thread(target=check_thread, args=(args,components,i))
        thread_list.append(t)

    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.start()

    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.join()

    for res in result:
        print(res)

    return res

if __name__ == 'main':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(....)
    parser.add_argument(.....)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    components = ['comp1','comp2']
    while True:
        print('SELECTION MENU\n1)\n2)\n')
        option = raw_input('Enter option')
        if option=='1':
            res = check(args, components)
        if option=='2':
            <do something else>
        else:
            sys.exit(0)
```

I've tried using multiprocessing module with Process, pool. Tried passing a lock to check_thread, tried returning a value from check_thread() and using a queue to take in the values, but everytime it's the same result, execution is successful but the terminal gets stuck and printed output is shabby.
Is there any fix to this? I'm using python 2.7. I'm using a linux terminal.
Here is how the shabby output looks
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qT30.png)

Comment: can you produce an output example and explain it?

Comment: @YusefMaali i have added an image of how the output looks, moreover the terminal also gets stuck after execution

Comment: Can you make this a fully runnable example? After adding `result = []` and `check()`, the program worked for me.

Comment: Can you include operating system, how you run this (e.g., from the command line) and what that extra SELECTION MENU is? The fact that a single list is printed and that menu shows up hints there is something else in your program causing the problem.

Comment: @tdelaney I have added more detail into the code. I have a feeling that it is the subprocess call that is causing the issue. I wanted to get the output from subprocess.check_output for each thread and then append it to my results.

Answer (score 0):

You should use queue module not list.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

# Define an output queue
output = mp.Queue()

# define a example function
def function(params, output):
    """ Generates a random string of numbers, lower- and uppercase chars. """
    # Process params and store results in res variable
    output.put(res)

# Setup a list of processes that we want to run
processes = [mp.Process(target=function, args=(5, output)) for x in range(10)]

# Run processes
for p in processes:
    p.start()

# Exit the completed processes
for p in processes:
    p.join()

# Get process results from the output queue
results = [output.get() for p in processes]

print(results)
```

Comment: it's the same result as before execution completes but the output is printed in a messed up way all over the terminal and the terminal itself is stuck. As mentioned in the question I did try out using a queue before but it was of no help.